# Transpose and insert subquery into outer query (SQL, select)

Tags: sql, sql-server

Through a subquery I'm trying to insert values and categories into columns of the outer query.

This makes it more complex than a simple tranpose. The column header of the 'origin' column needs to be inserted as a value of another column and the value of the 'origin' column goes into yet another column as such:

```
CYWP    Name  Qty       PR2
201607  M3    618400    0
201607  R1    329400    0
201607  M1    100056    0
201607  M2    20800     0
201607  R2    878921    113884
```

becomes:

```
CYWP    Name  Qty
201607  M3    618400
201607  R1    329400
201607  M1    100056
201607  M2    20800
201607  R2    878921
201607  PR2   113884
```

The code I have so far;

```
select  p.CuttingYearWeekPlanned, ps.Name, 
    sum(case    when p.ProductionStateIdTo = 2 or p.ProductionStateIdTo =101
                then (  case when p.QuantityPlannedAdjusted > 0
                        then p.QuantityPlannedAdjusted
                        else p.QuantityPlanned end)
                else (  case when p.QuantityPlannedAdjusted > 0 
                        then ceiling(convert(decimal(10,1),p.QuantityPlannedAdjusted)/100)*100
                        else ceiling(convert(decimal(10,1),p.QuantityPlanned)/100)*100 end)
                end) as qtyplanned,
    sum(case    when p.ProductionStateIdTo = 101 and b.QuantityPreR2OrPlastic > 0
                then b.QuantityPreR2OrPlastic
                else 0
                end) as PR2

from ProductionOrder p

inner join ProductionState ps on p.ProductionStateIdTo = ps.ProductionStateId
inner join Batch b  on p.BatchId = b.BatchId

group by p.CuttingYearWeekPlanned, ps.Name
```

The difficulty is that the values in column 'Qty' come from a different table then the values of column 'PR2'. The 'group by' clause in the outer query starts messing with my sums with every attempt I make to transpose and insert the results of the PR2 column.

Comment: **update**: The table is the temporary result of the query underneath and not source data.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a `union all`.  I have no idea what relationship your query has to your question -- the question mentions one table, but the query has many.

Here is the idea:

```
select CYWP, Name, Qty
from t
union all
select CYWP, 'PR2', Qty
from t
where PR2 <> 0;
```